# Why django_admin_log table is empty in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web application where I'm using Django 2.0.8 and Django Rest Framework to build a RESTful API. I have build some endpoint for basic CRUD operations. The problem is now I am trying to view log to my admin Dashboard. (Custom Admin Panel). But when I browsed my Database (PostgreSQL), I found that I have `django_admin_log` table but it is totally empty. But I created some object with those endpoints. Doesn't Django keep logs of user's activities by default? Or am I missing something?

**PS: I was authenticated while creating those objects**

**django_admin_log table**

[image: django_admin_log table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django logs actions done only via the Admin Panel. You can create custom logic to create records in the admin log table using the [LogEntry](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py) model from django.contrib.admin.models.

Comment: Oh !! So I had a wrong idea about the logging !!! Thanks for your information. :D I'll accept yours as the answer.